# Android Studio Virtual Device stop working

Tags: android, android-studio, android-virtual-device

I failed to sync the Main Activity with the resource folder and then my Virtual Device (VD) keeps exiting before running the app.

I have tried:

- Run previous app that I programmed which ran smoothly before but still the VD doesn't work (So it's not the app it's the VD)
- Mess around with the settings in AVD by increasing RAM amount to 2gb and put it to run on graphic card, and then the VD won't even cold boot.
- Delete and reinstall the VD but then it says cannot remove device, check .idea log (which I don't know where to look for) And then the VD disappeared from AVD, but inside my disk C, it still takes up space so not completely removed.

Now, my disk is almost full and I can't completely remove the two VD that I installed. Is there a way to manually remove them or do I have to completely uninstall Android Studio?

Answer (score 0):

You can find Emulator folder in,

> C:\Users\YourUserName\AppData\Local.android\avd

You will find your AVDs there. Make sure to turn on "show hidden folders".

Comment: Yes, I found it but I don't know if deleting the folder will completely delete it or not.

Comment: Delete the folder with the device's name. It'll do the job.